# Find changes quickly in larger SQL database?

Tags: informix

There is a Java Swing application which uses an Informix database. I have user rights granted for the Swing application (i.e. no source code), and read only access to a mirror of the database.

Sometimes I need to find a database column, which is backing a GUI element (TextBox, TableField, Label...). What would be best approach to find out which database column and table is holding the data shown e.g. in a TextBox?

My general approach is to capture the state of the database. Commit a change using the GUI and then capture the state of the database again. Then I need to examine the difference. I've already tried:

1. Use the `nrows` field of `systables`: Didn't work, because the number in `nrows` does not seem to be a realtime representation of the row count.
2. Create a script with `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` for all tables: didn't work because too many tables (> 5000). Also tried to optimize by removing empty tables, but there are still too many left.

Is there a simple solution that I'm missing?

Comment: There are some SQL clients which can search a database for a specific (column) value. Which SQL client are you using? (although I guess this could never be "quick")

Comment: Since executing `COUNT(*)` on all tables is slow as hell, I assume looking for a value in a table will be even slower :(

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the [Change Data Capture](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.cdc.doc/ids_cdc_057.htm) API and check if this suits your needs

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work, because I don't have permissions to change the settings in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.cdc.doc/ids_cdc_051.htm?lang=de

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a simple solution.

You probably need to build yourself a map of the database, or a data dictionary for it.  It sounds as though you can eliminate many of the tables from consideration since they're empty — at least for a preliminary pass.  If you're dealing with information in a text box, the chances are it is some sort of character data; you can analyze which (non-empty) tables which contain longer character strings, and they'd be the primary targets of your searches.  If the schema is badly designed with lots of `VARCHAR(255)` columns even though the columns normally only hold short strings, life is more difficult.  Over time, you can begin to classify tables and columns so that you end up knowing where to look for parts of the application.

One problem to beware of: the `tabid` in `informix.systables` isn't necessarily as stable as you'd like.  Your data dictionary needs to record its own `dd_tabid` for the table it describes, and can store the last known `tabid` from `informix.systables`, but it needs to be ready to find a new `tabid` value on occasion.  You should probably only mark data in your dictionary for logical deletion.

To some extent, this assumes you can create a database in which to record this information.  If you can't create an Informix database, you may have to use something else (MySQL, or SQLite, perhaps) to store the data dictionary.  Alternatively, go to your DBA team and ask them for the information.  Unless you're trying something self-evidently untoward, they're likely to help (but politics can get in the way — I've no idea how collegial your teams are).